# Can I check if a Windows process is running from a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a server-side tracker for a video game that runs against an API to update the player's performance, but I only want to track the player's activity when he is playing the game. Since there's no way to know that just from the API, nor any other service, I'm looking at other ways to tell the tracker to update when the user is running the game's process.

I'm trying to rule out desktop applications and a Chrome extension seems like a good compromise. However, I'm aware of the security implications that this has and I know Chrome has some concerns on browser-OS communications. Is there a way to safely achieve this in the scope of a Chrome extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions API does not provide any methods to get the process info other than that of the [browser process](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes). You can try using the [native client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) as a part of the chrome extension.

Comment: Should be [Native Host/Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), not Native Client. NaCl is sandboxed.